# Android leak Eclipse Memory Analyzer Photo inside

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory-leaks

i got a leak on my app 168mb on memory
and i have tried to understand where the leak are more then two days.
i added the location i think the leak is
,thanks for helping

thanks for all the helper.
[Link] to Img[1]
  ***[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WwCS.png

***Log Cat :***

```
 I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 651(39KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 155MB/171MB, paused 506us total 12.495ms
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2546(202KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(114MB) LOS objects, 28% free, 40MB/56MB, paused 725us total 49.030ms
I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 541(47KB) AllocSpace objects, 12(7MB) LOS objects, 9% free, 157MB/173MB, paused 651us total 14.817ms
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 431(19KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 157MB/173MB, paused 486us total 23.604ms

 I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2265(177KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(114MB) LOS objects, 27% free, 42MB/58MB, paused 528us total 44.405ms
```

***Eclipse Memory Analyser :***

Problem Suspect 1

```
One instance of "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView" loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x12cd1540" occupies 51,841,080 (30.62%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "byte[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".
```

Keywords
    byte[]
    android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x12cd1540

Details »
  Problem Suspect 2

```
One instance of "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView" loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x12cd1540" occupies 47,187,000 (27.87%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "byte[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".
```

Keywords
    byte[]
    android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x12cd1540

***onItemClick***

```
public class onItemClick extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private  String getImg1String, getImg2String, getImg3String, getImg4String, getImg5String;
    private Dialog progressDialog;
    private String GEThouseNumber, GETstreet, GETcity;
    private int position;
    private ImageView BIGimg, Image1IMG, Image2IMG, Image3IMG, Image4IMG, Image5IMG;
    private int nowX = 0;
    private int StopX = 0;
//    final ImageView[] ImageViewName = new ImageView[]{Image1IMG, Image2IMG, Image3IMG, Image4IMG, Image5IMG};
    private String[] StringUrlArray = new String[5];
    private int counter = 0;
    private Context context;
    private   MyApplication Application;
    private int width;
    private  int height;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_on_item_click);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.title_activity_on_item_click);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                    ImageView customSearchImg = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.locationImg); // cast it
            customSearchImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Uri IntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + GETcity + "," + GETstreet + " " + GEThouseNumber);
                    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, IntentUri);
                    startActivity(mapIntent);
                }
            });
            ImageView phoneImageView = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.phone); 
            phoneImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:04-696-5444   "));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            ImageView SendMailImageView = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.mail); 
            SendMailImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    i.setType("message/rfc822");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"nadlangolan@gmail.com"});
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "התעניינות בנכס");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                    try {
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(onItemClick.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        width = size.x;
        height = size.y;
        context = this;
        //showProgressBar(context.getResources().getString(R.string.Loading).toString());
        //check if there is internet
        if (AppStatus.getInstance(context).isOnline()) {
            try {
                onCreateInslaize();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                dismissProgressBar();
                buildDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.noInternet).toString());
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void onCreateInslaize() {
        try {

            Application = ((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext());
            //showProgressBar(getResources().getString(R.string.Loading).toString());
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            definitionView();
            ProessDataBackground PData = new ProessDataBackground();
            PData.execute();
            handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 8000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            buildDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.itemOnClickOnCreate).toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
            handler.removeCallbacks(changeImage);
        finish();
    }

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable changeImage = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (counter + 1 >= StringUrlArray.length) {
                    counter = 0;
                    fadeOutAndHideImage(StringUrlArray[counter]);
                } else {
                    counter++;
                    fadeOutAndHideImage(StringUrlArray[counter]);
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 8000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                buildDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.galleryError).toString());
            }
        }
    };

    // define all the view items
    public void definitionView() {
        BIGimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemcustom_BigIMG);
        BIGimg.setOnTouchListener(this);
        Image1IMG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemcustom_img1);
        Image2IMG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemcustom_img2);
        Image3IMG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemcustom_img3);
        Image4IMG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemcustom_img4);
        Image5IMG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemcustom_img5);

    }

    public void itemCDF(View view) {
        try {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.itemcustom_next:
                    if (counter + 1 == 5) {
                        fadeOutAndHideImage(StringUrlArray[0]);
                        counter = 0;
                    } else {
                        counter++;
                        fadeOutAndHideImage(StringUrlArray[counter]);
                    }
                    break;

                case R.id.itemcustom_pre:
                    if (counter - 1 == -1) {
                        counter = 4;
                        fadeOutAndHideImage(StringUrlArray[counter]);
                    } else {
                        counter--;
                        fadeOutAndHideImage(StringUrlArray[counter]);

                    }
                    break;

                case R.id.itemcustom_img1:
                    counter = 0;
                    fadeOutAndHideImage(StringUrlArray[counter]);
                    break;
                case R.id.itemcustom_img2:
                    counter = 1;
                    fadeOutAndHideImage(StringUrlArray[counter]);
                    break;
                case R.id.itemcustom_img3:
                    counter = 2;
                    fadeOutAndHideImage(StringUrlArray[counter]);
                    break;
                case R.id.itemcustom_img4:
                    counter = 3;
                    fadeOutAndHideImage(StringUrlArray[counter]);
                    break;
                case R.id.itemcustom_img5:
                    counter = 4;
                    fadeOutAndHideImage(StringUrlArray[counter]);
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            buildDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.onItemClickImageClick).toString());
        }
    }
    class ProessDataBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Bundle GetExtra = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (GetExtra == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                try {
                    position = GetExtra.getInt("position");
                    GEThouseNumber = Application.getHouseNumberFromApp(position);
                    GETstreet = Application.getStreetFromApp(position);
                    GETcity =  Application.getCityFromApp(position);
                    getImg1String = Application.getIMG1FromApp(position);
                    getImg2String = Application.getIMG2FromApp(position);
                    getImg3String = Application.getIMG3FromApp(position);
                    getImg4String = Application.getIMG4FromApp(position);
                    getImg5String = Application.getIMG5FromApp(position);
                    StringUrlArray = new String[]{getImg1String, getImg2String, getImg3String, getImg4String, getImg5String};

                    publishProgress();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    buildDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.getDataOnClick).toString());
                }
            }
            return null;
    }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            TextView rooms = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemClick_roomsVal);
            TextView price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemClick_priceVal);
            TextView floor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemClick_FloorVal);
            TextView houseNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.onItem_numHouseVal);
            TextView city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemClick_cityVal);
            TextView street = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemClick_streetVal);
            TextView totalSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemClick_sizeHouseVal);
            TextView buildingSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemClick_BuildingSize);
            TextView type = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.onItem_typesVal);
            TextView buildingSitu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemClick_houseSituVal);
            TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemClick_descriptionVal);
            if (Application.getRoomsFromApp(position) % 1 == 0) {
                int rm = (int)Application.getRoomsFromApp(position);
                rooms.setText(" " + rm + " ");
            } else {
                rooms.setText(" " + Application.getRoomsFromApp(position) + " ");
            }
            price.setText(" " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(Application.getPriceFromApp(position)) + "₪");
            floor.setText(" " + Application.getFloorFromApp(position) + " ");
            houseNumber.setText(" " +GEThouseNumber + " ");
            city.setText(" " + GETcity + " ");
            street.setText(" " + GETstreet + " ");
            totalSize.setText(" " + Application.getTotalSizeFromApp(position) + " מ״ר");

            buildingSize.setText(" " + Application.getBuildSizeFromApp(position) + " מ״ר");
            type.setText(" " + Application.getTypeFromApp(position) + " ");
            buildingSitu.setText(" " + Application.getBuildSitFromApp(position) + " ");
            description.setText(" " + Application.getDescripsionFromApp(position) + " ");
            Picasso.with(context).load(Application.getIMG1FromApp(position)).resize(width,height/ 4).into(BIGimg);
            Picasso.with(context).load(Application.getIMG1FromApp(position)).resize(55, 55).into(Image1IMG);
            Picasso.with(context).load(Application.getIMG2FromApp(position)).resize(55, 55).into(Image2IMG);
            Picasso.with(context).load(Application.getIMG3FromApp(position)).resize(55, 55).into(Image3IMG);
            Picasso.with(context).load(Application.getIMG4FromApp(position)).resize(55, 55).into(Image4IMG);
            Picasso.with(context).load(Application.getIMG5FromApp(position)).resize(55,55).into(Image5IMG);

        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
}
        public void buildDialog(String msg) {
        try {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(onItemClick.this);
            builder.setMessage(msg)
                    .setTitle(R.string.alertDialogTitle)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private void fadeOutAndHideImage(final String imgUrl) {
        try {
            Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
            fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            fadeOut.setDuration(600);
            fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    Picasso.with(context).load(imgUrl).resize(width, height / 4).placeholder(R.drawable.noimg).into(BIGimg);
                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }
            });
            BIGimg.startAnimation(fadeOut);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            buildDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.onItemClickImageEffect).toString());
        }
    }
    public void dismissProgressBar() {
        try {
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
                progressDialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            buildDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.dismissProgressBarogressBarError).toString());
        }
    }

    public void showProgressBar(final String msg) {
        try {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", msg, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            buildDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.showProgressBarError).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

***Adapter Code*** 
:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int RentOrSell = 0;
    private MyApplication Application;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        try {
            this.context=context;
            Application = ((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext());
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
              getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            width = metrics.widthPixels;
            height = metrics.heightPixels;

        }catch (Exception e){ }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Application.getSizePosts();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView customtitle, customPriceVal, customRoom, customFloor, PriceTextView,cityNameVal,streetNameVal
                ,numHouseVal,buildSize;
        ImageView BigIMG;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder;

        try {
            if(convertView == null || convertView.getTag()==null) {
                holder = new Holder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
                holder.BigIMG = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_BIG_IMG);
                holder.cityNameVal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cityNameVal);
                holder.streetNameVal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.streetNameVal);
                holder.numHouseVal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numHouseVal);
                holder.buildSize = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buildSize);
                holder.PriceTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceText);
                holder.customtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customTitle);
                holder.customPriceVal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customPriceVal);
                holder.customRoom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customRoomVal);
                holder.customFloor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customFloorVal);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                if (RentOrSell == 0) {
                    holder.PriceTextView.setText(" שכירות : ");
                } else {
                    holder.PriceTextView.setText(" מחיר : ");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.customtitle.setText(" "+ Application.getCityFromApp(position) + " , " + Application.getStreetFromApp(position) +
                    " " + Application.getHouseNumberFromApp(position)+" ");

            holder.customPriceVal.setText(" " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(Application.getPriceFromApp(position)) + "₪");

            if (Application.getRoomsFromApp(position) % 1 == 0) {
                int rm = (int)Application.getRoomsFromApp(position);
                holder.customRoom.setText(" " + rm + " ");
            } else {
                holder.customRoom.setText(" " + Application.getRoomsFromApp(position) + " ");
            }
            holder.cityNameVal.setText(" " +  Application.getCityFromApp(position) + " ");
            holder.streetNameVal.setText(" " + Application.getStreetFromApp(position) + " ");
            holder.numHouseVal.setText(" " + Application.getHouseNumberFromApp(position) + " ");
            holder.buildSize.setText(" " + Application.getBuildSizeFromApp(position) + " ");
            holder.customFloor.setText(" " + Application.getFloorFromApp(position) + " ");

            Log.i("1", "1" + "");

            Picasso.with(context).load(Application.getIMG1FromApp(position)).resize(width / 2, height / 3)
                    .into(holder.BigIMG);
            Log.i("1", "2" + "");

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent onItemClickedIntent = new Intent(context, onItemClick.class);
                    onItemClickedIntent.putExtra("position", position);
                    context.startActivity(onItemClickedIntent);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("1", "Error setView On Adapter ");
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

i delete from sellActivity the "build dialog " ,"dismiss progress" , show progress because of the letter list

***SellListView ( The Activity the send to the list view )***

```
:   
    public class sellListView extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ListView lv;
        private Context context;
        private Toolbar toolbar;
        private Dialog progressDialog;
        private List<GetDataBaseCounstarctour> posts = null;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sell_list_view);
           toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            InsalizeThingOfOnCreate();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            finish();
   }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            try {
                dismissProgressBar();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        public void InsalizeThingOfOnCreate() {
            this.context =  this;
            try {

                ImageView customSearchImg = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.customSearchImg); // cast it
                customSearchImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                buildDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.ImgONClick).toString());
            }

    //            Refresh Img On Click
            ImageView refreshImage = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.refreshImage); 
            refreshImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        if ( ((MyApplication)getApplicationContext()).getNumOfObjects() != ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).getSizePosts()) {
                            showProgressBar(getResources().getString(R.string.Loading).toString());
                            RemoteDataTask getData = new RemoteDataTask();
                            getData.execute();
                            dismissProgressBar();
                      {} catch (Exception e) {
                        buildDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.ImgONClick).toString());
                    }
                }
            });

            if (AppStatus.getInstance(this).isOnline()) {
                try {
                    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                    Parse.initialize(this, xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx);
                    RemoteDataTask getData = new RemoteDataTask();
                    getData.execute();
                }catch (Exception e){}}
            else {
                try{
                    dismissProgressBar();
                    buildDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.noInternet).toString());
                }catch (Exception e){}
        }
        }

        private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            public RemoteDataTask() {
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                showProgressBar(context.getResources().getString(R.string.Loading).toString());
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    posts = new ArrayList<GetDataBaseCounstarctour>();
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Sell");
                    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> postList, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                posts.clear();
                                for (ParseObject post : postList) {
                                    ParseFile f1 = (ParseFile) post.get("ImageFile");
                                    ParseFile f2 = (ParseFile) post.get("ImageFile2");
                                    ParseFile f3 = (ParseFile) post.get("ImageFile3");
                                    ParseFile f4 = (ParseFile) post.get("ImageFile4");
                                    ParseFile f5 = (ParseFile) post.get("ImageFile5");
                                    GetDataBaseCounstarctour GDB = new GetDataBaseCounstarctour(post.getString("city"), post.getString("street"), post.getString("totalSize")
                                            , post.getString("buildSize"), post.getString("typeBuilding"), post.getString("BuildingSituation"), post.getString("FloorNumber"),
                                            post.getDouble("roomNumber"), post.getInt("price"), post.getString("HouseNumber"), post.getString("description"), post.getObjectId()
                                            , f1.getUrl(), f2.getUrl(), f3.getUrl(), f4.getUrl(), f5.getUrl());
                                    posts.add(GDB);
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                            }
                            publishProgress();
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
              buildDialog(context.getResources().getString(R.string.errorGetDataFromServer).toString());
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                Log.i("1", "onPost ");
                dismissProgressBar();
                ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext()).setNumOfObjects(posts.size());
                ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext()).setPosts(posts);
                lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                posts = null;

                lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(context));
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need to see your code.

Comment: i will add now the class code